# mdadm -c does not set the mode and so cannot be first option

Tags: mdadm

I am following the instruction [here](https://perdigaosarcade.com/2020/10/19/install-new-disk-in-wd-my-cloud-gen-1/?fbclid=IwAR35gZD5FbnWmGlWoPuonuHGydrGG8ms7i69p2KMGjuRsGYSpUW7yeMM_gc) I am stuck at this line

```
mdadm –create /dev/md0 –level=1 –metadata=0.9 –raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

I get the following error when I try to run it

mdadm: -c does not set mode, and so cannot be the first option.

Ps: in my case I have sda no sdc

Comment: Did you copy-paste that command from somewhere? It looks like the dashes are [unicode en dashes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) not ordinary ASCII characters - try retyping them

Comment: @steeldriver i have type this "-" caracther manuelly in the terminal. are there two diffrent characters that i have to type?

Comment: @steeldriver yes you where right the "-" betweeen –raid-devices is not the same as the "–" in front of the word. Thank you very much for your help